# How to set custom Tax in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-api, tax

I am new to Shopify. Can someone help me pointed the right track?

I need to change the Tax on Checkout. By default, is it based on Customer's Shipping Address and I need to set it based on the Location of the Item conditionally.

I've read multiple resources and I can't seem to see the right approach.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Taxes are calculated at checkout. As such, it is done by Shopify. So if you have problems with taxes, your only recourse is to set taxes in Shopify settings as best you can. If that does not work for you, you probably have a setting not supported by Shopify.